# CSS Simple Dropdown click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to build a very simple functionality to create a drop down under a certain text field when its clicked.

```js
$(".val").children("div").on("click", function() {
  alert("CLICK");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.val {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container:focus-within .val {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="lab" contenteditable>LABEL</div>
  <div class="val">
    <div>VAL1</div>
    <div>VAL2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Main problem comes with the click function which it never gets triggered... (I guess it runs first the lost focus in CSS and then no click is done in that element as its hidden?)

Even though there is an "alert" there, I want to use the `click` event to set the value back in the `.lab` field like a dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the solution below, clicking the `<div>` element with the `.lab` class style applied will fire the first event listener and the dropdown list will be visible. Clicking on any of the `<div>` elements in the dropdown list that implements the `.clickable` class style fires the second event listener. In this case, the dropdown list is closed and the id value of the clicked `<div>` element is printed to the console.

```js
/* Fires when clicking the <div> element with the ".lab" class style applied. */
$(document).on('click', '.lab', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.clear();
  console.log("The dropdown list opens.");
  
  /* Open Dropdown List */
  $('.val').attr('style', 'display: inline-block');
  
  /* Fires when clicking the <div> element with the ".clickable" class style applied. */
  $(document).on('click', '.clickable', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.clear();
    console.log(`Clicked Container ID: ${$(this).attr('id')}`);
    
    /* Close Dropdown List */
    $('.val').attr('style', 'display: none');
  });
  
  $(document).on('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.val').attr('style', 'display: none');
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.lab {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.val {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container:focus-within .val {
  display: block;
}
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lab" contenteditable>Open Dropdown</div>

    <div class="val">
      <div id="first" class="clickable">First</div>
      <div id="second" class="clickable">Second</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I like your approach :) But I see it is not being hidden when clicking outside... Mainly I was using CSS for this with **.container:focus-within** which was removing the class automatically. Do you mean its better to use the js to show hide than CSS for the overall Im trying?

Comment: I fixed the problem you mentioned. Developing dynamic behavior with CSS is hard to understand. I prefer developing solutions with JS because it is more portable and repeatable.

Comment: Yup I think I wont spend much time in pure CSS... It is quite interesting what is able to do but indeed can be really confusing to read... Thanks!